# Some questions about solidity?

Tags: go-ethereum, solidity, dapp-development, ethereum-wallet-dapp

1.

```
address myaddress="0x........."
mapping(address=>uint) map;
map[myaddress]=100;
```

Does mapping has the limit? When use mapping, how to free space about the mapping.

2. In solidity, getFilterChanges function could get the event, but it only receive the event log once, how to know the event happens twice?

Comment: Please ask 1 question per post, with a clear title: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39223/one-post-with-multiple-questions-or-multiple-posts

Answer (score 1):

Keys for mapping are hashed to derive the storage address, so the limit to a mapping is the logical space addressable by the key type.  All mapping slots are implied to be pre-initialized to 0 (or the equivalent of the type being mapped to).  This means, in your example you can read and write to any address in the `address` space.  You can delete an element with the `delete` keyword however if a mapping element is a type that itself contains a mapping (say in a struct), deleting the element will not delete the data in the struct's mapping member.

`delete map[myaddress]`

Solidity and contracts in general have no access to Events. I think `getFilterChanges` must be from some external API you're looking at?

Comment: 1.delete would cost much gas compare to  set the value to initial state.                                    2. getFilterChanges function could only capture the event message **once** ,before that and after that   getFilterChanges has no changes (could not capture the event message).

Comment: I would add that, although the OP said "to free space", it does not free space in the usual computer storage sense. Indeed the used / free storage areas are not referenced in an index.  On the other hand, although `delete` is more expensive in gas, I believe it saves storage space on the Ethereum node as the Merkle trie of storage is truncated. The trie is not truncated after setting the storage to `0`.